# How to append something inside an element with unique id but general class , in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a multiple page like this :

```
<div data-role="page" data-add-back-btn="true" id="Gallery1" class="gallery-page">
    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>First Gallery</h1>
    </div>
   <div data-role="content">    
        <ul class="gallery">

        </ul>   
   </div>
</div>

<div data-role="page" data-add-back-btn="true" id="Gallery2" class="gallery-page"> 
    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Second Gallery</h1>
    </div>
   <div data-role="content">    
        <ul class="gallery">

        </ul>       
   </div> 
</div>

<div data-role="page" data-add-back-btn="true" id="Gallery3" class="gallery-page">
    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Third Gallery</h1>
    </div>
   <div data-role="content">    
        <ul class="gallery">

        </ul>   
   </div>
</div>
```

Now i want to append something inside the

```
<ul class="gallery">

</ul>
```

of every page. I know how to append something in a class or in an id. But how do i append something inside this class , that is inside a page with specific id ?

If it was just a class i would do: `(".Gallery" + i).append(..)` , if it was an id i would 
 `("#Gallery" + i).append(..)` .

I am not sure what to do in this case.

Comment: When you say page with specific id do you mean you want to append specific stuff to ul with the class of 'gallery' that belong to a page with a specific id for the body element ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

simply do:

```
$('#Gallery' + i ).find('.gallery').append('Something');
```

where `i` is your Number

Which is a faster variant of DOM traversal which in your case seems not needed and as we all like to keep things simple you can do:

```
$('#Gallery'+i +' .gallery').append('Something');
```

http://api.jquery.com/find/

Comment: hmm :) . Is .find supported on every browser? This actually is a jquery mobile app.

Comment: @JohnyJaz - `.find()` isn't required. You could simply do `$('#Gallery' + i + ' .gallery')`

Comment: sure it is! Give it a try, you'll be amazed ;)

Comment: @j08691 we heard lot of times that `.find()` is surprisingly faster than that, any way great tip!

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan - I doubt you'll notice any speed difference in such a simple markup example here. And I didn't say not to use `.find()`, just that it wasn't required.

Comment: @j08691 true true, I fully support your thoughts! I'll mention our disq in my answer.

Comment: This is good, although jQuery docs say $("something").appendTo("#gallery") is faster than $("#gallery").append("something")